# issue with page show event in Jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am unable to fire an event on page show. In my home page I have a select menu which will dynamically get the values from DB. My functionality is working fine but event does not happen. I need to fire my function when I my page gets loaded. How to do that

```
<div data-role="page" id="homePage">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>
            Heading
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <select name="select-choice" id="select-choice">
            <option value="Select Category">Select Category
        </select>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have fired the event as follows, but function does not fired

```
 $(document).on("pageshow", "#homePage", function () {
     alert("on page show event occurred!! ");
     // I did my logic here...                                       
 });
```

GIve some suggestions that which event is better to use and how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried "pagehide" event instead of "pageshow"?

Comment: No, But I need to load it on page load or page init or page crete events

Comment: I understand this, yes, but "pageshow" works with previous page and the "pagehide" works with next page. Maybe it also affects .on() with 3 parameters...

Comment: alert is fired before page loads or not..if it fires before page load your logic part is having issue.

Comment: 1) Are you redirecting from pageX to homePage? 2) are you using _single page_ or _multi-page_ model? 3) where are you placing your code, `head`, `body`, inside `data-role=page` div?

Comment: @Regent `pagehide` fires on current page, `pageshow` fires on next page once shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this in your page and you will get sequence in which events fired.
For the convenient event that fired instead of console.log insert your function call.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate',function(){console.log('pagebeforecreate');});
$(document).on('pagecreate',function(){console.log('pagecreate');});
$(document).on('pageinit',function(){console.log('pageinit');});
$(document).on('pagebeforehide',function(){console.log('pagebeforehide');});
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow',function(){console.log('pagebeforeshow');});
$(document).on('pageremove',function(){console.log('pageremove');});
$(document).on('pageshow',function(){console.log('pageshow');});
$(document).on('pagehide',function(){console.log('pagehide');});

   $(window).load(function () {
   console.log("window loaded");
   });
    $(function () {
  console.log('document ready');
    });
    $(window).on('unload',function () {console.log("window unloaded");});
```